# Vuex - get module property from component

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

Before I added a module, I had a Vuex store with a data property, `baseUrl`, which I could access from a component like :

```
this.$store.state.baseUrl
```

Now I have added a module to the Vuex store, and moved the baseUrl property inside the module:

```
export const module1 = {

    state: {
        baseUrl: '',
    }
}
```

Module is included in Vuex:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({

    modules: {  module1  },
```

But now `this.$store.state.baseUrl` becomes undefined. 
I thought the module properties would be merged into the Vuex store, so I would be able to access properties with the exact same code.

How do I access the module properties? If I have to say `this.$store.state.module1.baseUrl` , I have to update all the code everywhere when I move a property from the Vuex into a module. And when moving a property from one module to another I have to update the code everywhere to change the module name.

However even `this.$store.state.module1.baseUrl` didn't work. I got `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` .

**EDIT**: Correction! I wrote `this.$store.module1.state.baseUrl`, so when I changed to `this.$store.state.module1.baseUrl` it does work.

So is this the correct way to access module properties - I have to specify the module name? (and go through all the code base when moving property inside module).

Answer (score 0):

Like you already pointet out in your edit, you have to use `this.$store.state.module1.baseUrl` to access the state of a `module`.

But that isn't the only way, you also can use [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) to a access the state from within a component:

```
YourComponent.vue
import { mapState } from 'vuex'  // outside of export default

computed: {
    ...mapState('module1', ['baseUrl'])
}
```

`baseUrl` is now accesable via `this`.

Comment: Interesting, but I saw that I could use getters, where I don't need to specify the module name. I have to look more into mapState though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getters` seems to be a good way - I don't have to specify a module name when getting a property.

So if I have :

```
export const module1 = {

    state: { 
        baseUrl: '',
    },
    getters: {  
        baseUrl: state => state.baseUrl
    }
```

I can get the property in a component with: `this.$store.getters.baseUrl`

So if I want I could move the `baseUrl` and `getter` into a different module, and the code would still work.